# How to get impress.js to work in my Flask/ Bootstrap stack

Tags: javascript, impress.js

I'am using a flask backend and set up a bootstrap grid including navbar (nothing special, I try to learn web-development).
My app is working so far, but any time I start impress presentation, my bootstrap navbar is completely inactive, it shows the buttons, but no one returns hovering style or follow links.

I found out that bootstrap and impress are no friends together.

My template loads

```
<header>
bootstrap.min.css
font-awesome.min.css
main.css
presentation.css 
</header>

<body>
    <container 1>
        bootstrap navbar
    </container 1>
    <container 2>
        *my dynamic content (inclusive impress presentation)*
    </container 2>
    <scripts>
    jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js
    popper.min.js
    bootstrap.min.js
    jmpress.js
    $(impress).impress("goTo", "overview")
    <scripts>
</body>
```

Does anyone got an idea, how to get my navbar and impress working together ?

Thank you !

Comment: Sounds like a transparent div is covering the navbar. You could try moving it above the impress container using `z-index: 10001;` or something. Did you right-click the inactive (covered) navbar and select "inspect element" yet?

Comment: Hi and thank you for your response !
After a while I found out, that there was 
class .impress-enabled  { pointer-events: none }
I disabled the class and my toolbar was accessable again.

Thank you so far